# multiply and summing certain columns based on name pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a small sample data set:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
  'measure1_x': [10,12,20,30,21],
  'measure2_x':[11,12,10,3,3],
  'measure3_x':[10,0,12,1,1],
  'measure1_y': [1,2,2,3,1],
  'measure2_y':[1,1,1,3,3],
  'measure3_y':[1,0,2,1,1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.reindex_axis([
    'measure1_x','measure2_x', 'measure3_x','measure1_y','measure2_y','measure3_y'
], axis=1)
```

it looks like:

```
      measure1_x  measure2_x  measure3_x  measure1_y  measure2_y  measure3_y
          10          11          10           1           1           1
          12          12           0           2           1           0
          20          10          12           2           1           2
          30           3           1           3           3           1
          21           3           1           1           3           1
```

i created the column names almost the same except for '_x' and '_y' to help identify which pair should be multiplying: i want to multiply the pair with the same column name when '_x' and '_y' are disregarded, then i want sum the numbers to get a total number, keep in mind my actual data set is huge and the columns are not in this perfect order so this naming is a way for identifying correct pairs to multiply:

**total = measure1_x * measure1_y + measure2_x * measure2_y + measure3_x * measure3_y**

**so desired output:**

```
measure1_x  measure2_x  measure3_x  measure1_y  measure2_y  measure3_y   total

 10          11          10           1           1           1           31 
 12          12           0           2           1           0           36 
 20          10          12           2           1           2           74
 30           3           1           3           3           1          100
 21           3           1           1           3           1           31
```

my attempt and thought process, but cannot proceed anymore syntax wise:

```
#first identify the column names that has '_x' and '_y', then identify if 
#the column names are the same after removing '_x' and '_y', if the pair has 
#the same name then multiply them, do that for all pairs and sum the results 
#up to get the total number

for colname in df.columns:
if "_x".lower() in colname.lower() or "_y".lower() in colname.lower():
    if "_x".lower() in colname.lower():  
        colnamex = colname
    if "_y".lower() in colname.lower():
        colnamey = colname

    #if colnamex[:-2] are the same for colnamex and colnamey then multiply and sum
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `filter` + `np.einsum`

Thought I'd try something a little different this time—

- get your `_x` and `_y` columns separately
- do a product-sum. This is very easy to specify with `einsum` (and *fast*).

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1) # optional, do this if your columns aren't sorted

i = df.filter(like='_x') 
j = df.filter(like='_y')
df['Total'] = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', i, j) # (i.values * j).sum(axis=1)
```

```
df
   measure1_x  measure2_x  measure3_x  measure1_y  measure2_y  measure3_y  Total
0          10          11          10           1           1           1     31
1          12          12           0           2           1           0     36
2          20          10          12           2           1           2     74
3          30           3           1           3           3           1    100
4          21           3           1           1           3           1     31
```

A slightly more robust version which filters out non-numeric columns and performs an assertion beforehand—

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1).select_dtypes(exclude=[object])
i = df.filter(regex='.*_x') 
j = df.filter(regex='.*_y')

assert i.shape == j.shape

df['Total'] = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', i, j)
```

If the assertion fails, the the assumptions of 1) your columns being numeric, and 2) the number of x and y columns being equal, as your question would suggest, do not hold for your actual dataset.

Comment: I was going to force a dot product somewhere to be cool.  Now I don't have to because I've been out-cooled with `einsum` (-:

Comment: @piRSquared I was trying to force one too, until I remembered how I'd been outcooled that day like this XD

Comment: `einsum` is always super cool, but doesn't this assume ordered columns?

Comment: @filippo Certainly the filter makes assumptions on the nature of the column names. But so does piR's answer. By the way, I've already added an optional `df.sort_index(axis=1)` step above in case it was needed.

Comment: uh completely missed `sort_index`!

Comment: i got 'TypeError: invalid data type for einsum'  , is it because i also have additional columns in there that do not need to be used in the calculation?  and they do not have the _x _y naming convention

Comment: so the _x and _y naming convention is for identifying only the columns needed for the calculation but i have other columns too

Comment: @Jessica I've added a more robust version of this. Try it. If the assertion fails, you know there's a problem with your data that you will badly need to revisit before testing either of our solutions again.

Comment: got this: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (340,54)->(340,54) (340,0)->(340,0)      i think i need to revisit my data set

Comment: @Jessica Yes, the assumption here is that the number of numeric x-valued columns == number of numeric y-value columns. Better take another look. Both mine, and piR's answers work well as long as the assumption holds.

Comment: i found out the problem, the j= datacombined.filter(like='_y') is not picking up any row, not sure why... need to figure it out

Comment: @Jessica you can try the regex version below and see if it makes a difference: `i = df.filter(regex='.*_x'); j = df.filter(regex='.*_y')` otherwise, check your column names

Answer (score 3):

- Use `df.columns.str.split` to generate a new MultiIndex
- Use `prod` with `axis` and `level` arguments
- Use `sum` with `axis` argument
- Use `assign` to create new column

---

```
df.assign(
    Total=df.set_axis(
        df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True),
        axis=1, inplace=False
    ).prod(axis=1, level=0).sum(1)
)

   measure1_x  measure2_x  measure3_x  measure1_y  measure2_y  measure3_y  Total
0          10          11          10           1           1           1     31
1          12          12           0           2           1           0     36
2          20          10          12           2           1           2     74
3          30           3           1           3           3           1    100
4          21           3           1           1           3           1     31
```

---

### Restrict dataframe to just columns that look like `'meausre[i]_[j]'`

```
df.assign(
    Total=df.filter(regex='^measure\d+_\w+$').pipe(
        lambda d: d.set_axis(
            d.columns.str.split('_', expand=True),
            axis=1, inplace=False
        )
    ).prod(axis=1, level=0).sum(1)
)
```

---

### Debugging

See if this gets you the correct Totals

```
d_ = df.copy()
d_.columns = d_.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

d_.prod(axis=1, level=0).sum(1)

0     31
1     36
2     74
3    100
4     31
dtype: int64
```

Comment: i tried with my actual dataset which is larger and got: TypeError: set_axis() got multiple values for argument 'axis'

Comment: Are you accidentally using `axis` twice in the `set_axis` call?

Comment: my actual dataset columns are not in perfect order, sorry if i do not understand your code fully, but where do you identify the correct pair to multiply based on name? or is it not needed?

Comment: Are you accidentally using axis twice in the set_axis call? :  no i copied and pasted your exact code

Comment: Try my updated suggestion.  Are your columns not restricted to just those that look like `measurei_j`?

Comment: the 'measures' are generic name for different names but it's in the format of  measure_x  and measure_y   ,  the measure part is the same

Comment: for example it would be 'number of tests_x' and 'number of tests_y',  'count number_x' and 'count number_y', etc.

Comment: Well unless I see the data that is causing the problem and my edited suggestions don't already help, I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: the _x and _y naming convention is for identifying only the columns needed for the calculation but i have other columns in the dataframe too, does this matter?

Comment: Yes, it matters.  My second suggestion attempts to filter only the relevant columns.  Otherwise, you'll need to filter it yourself and apply the concepts.